# python - global variables

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I found a Python tutorial on queue and threading. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Queue
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.q = q
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        process_data(self.name, self.q)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def process_data(threadName, q):
    while not exitFlag:
        queueLock.acquire()
        if not workQueue.empty():
            data = q.get()
            queueLock.release()
            print "%s processing %s" % (threadName, data)
            time.sleep(3)
            print "%s finished processing %s" % (threadName, data)
        else:
            queueLock.release()
        time.sleep(1)


threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
threads = []
threadID = 1

# Create new threads
for tName in threadList:
    thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    threadID += 1


# Fill the queue
queueLock.acquire()
for word in nameList:
    workQueue.put(word)
queueLock.release()

# Wait for queue to empty
while not workQueue.empty():
    pass

# Notify threads it's time to exit
exitFlag = 1

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

I am super new to Python and threading + queuing so pardon me.

I am intending to write a few thread classes (e.g: myThread1, myThread2, etc). In the main(), it will receive command line arguments and decides which thread class to create.

So I'm thinking of splitting myThread classes and main into a separate python file. And I also intend to move process_data method into myThread classes to perform a set of rules which will be different for each threadclasses. Think of it as encapsulation.

This is what I have tried:

mythread.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Queue
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.q = q
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        process_data(self.name, self.q)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def process_data(threadName, q):
    while not exitFlag:
        queueLock.acquire()
        if not workQueue.empty():
            data = q.get()
            queueLock.release()
            print "%s processing %s" % (threadName, data)
            time.sleep(3)
            print "%s finished processing %s" % (threadName, data)
        else:
            queueLock.release()
        time.sleep(1)
```

main.py

```
threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
threads = []
threadID = 1

# Create new threads
for tName in threadList:
    thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    threadID += 1


# Fill the queue
queueLock.acquire()
for word in nameList:
    workQueue.put(word)
queueLock.release()

# Wait for queue to empty
while not workQueue.empty():
    pass

# Notify threads it's time to exit
exitFlag = 1

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

There are a few problems that i'm facing now:

1. How can I pass exitFlag to myThread class? I tried setting it as a class variable but the `while not exitFlag` will never be true when I set `exitFlag=1` in main
2. How can I pass queueLock into the class? same thing here. Right now it is declared as global variable? and it also didn't work if I set it as a member variable for myThread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to #1 is don't use a global variable. Instead add a flag to your`myThread`subclass.

As for question #2, The`Queue`class was designed for multi-threaded programming, so its methods automatically handle all required locking details for you, thereby preventing simultaneous access problems. This means you don't really need the`queueLock`.

Incorporating both of these suggestions into your answer would result in something like this (untested):

main.py

```
from mythread import MyThread
import Queue
import threading

threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
threads = []
threadID = 1

# Create new threads
for tName in threadList:
    thread = MyThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    threadID += 1

# Fill the queue
for word in nameList:
    workQueue.put(word)

# Wait for queue to empty
while not workQueue.empty():
    pass

# Notify threads it's time to exit
for t in threads:
    t.stop()

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

mythread.py

```
import threading
import time

class MyThread (threading.Thread):  # note capitalization change
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.q = q
        self.__exitFlag = False
        self.__signal_lock = threading.Lock()
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        self.process_data()
        print "Exiting " + self.name
    def stop(self):
        with self.__signal_lock:
            self.__exitFlag = True
    def process_data(self):
        while not self.__exitFlag:
            if not self.q.empty():
                data = self.q.get()
                print "%s processing %s" % (self.name, data)
                time.sleep(3)
                print "%s finished processing %s" % (self.name, data)
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: hi tks for the solution. it works like a charm. one correction to your code though (in MyThread, replace workQueue with self.q).

Comment: Oops, missed one -- glad to have helped.

Comment: hello martineau, im back. i discover that its necessary to add queueLock. Without it, my program will not exit main thread if i have more threads than queue items.

Comment: It's unclear why you'd have more threads than queue items (not counting the main thread). Regardless, you can make a started thread object not prevent the main thread from exiting by setting its [daemon](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html?highlight=daemon#threading.Thread.daemon) property beforehand (its default initial value is inherited from the creating thread). In the code in my answer that could be accomplished by adding a `self.daemon = True` statement to the `MyThread.__init__()` constructor method.

Answer (score 1):

import your thread class from main.py and execute anything you want from main.py don't execute mythread.py, then let threads check exitFlag and alter it from main.py .

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution;

mythread_class.py

```
import threading
import time

class MyThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, threadname, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.threadname = threadname
        self.queue = q
        self.__exitFlag = False
        self.__signal_lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.threadname
        self.process_data()
        print "Exiting " + self.threadname

    def stop(self):
        with self.__signal_lock:
            self.__exitFlag = True

    def process_data(self):
        while not self.__exitFlag:
            if not self.queue.empty():
                data = self.queue.get()
                print "%s processing %s" % (self.threadname, data)
                time.sleep(3)
                print "%s finished processing %s" % (self.threadname, data)

            time.sleep(1)
```

main.py
    from mythread_class import MyThread
    import Queue
    import threading

```
threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
threads = []
threadID = 1

# Create new threads
for tName in threadList:
    thread = MyThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    threadID += 1

# Fill the queue
for word in nameList:
    workQueue.put(word)

# Wait for queue to empty
while not workQueue.empty():
    pass

# Notify threads it's time to exit
for t in threads:
    t.stop()

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

if you have multiple MyThread classes, simply replace this line to your other class:

```
thread = MyThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
```

--OR --

```
thread = MyThread2(threadID, tName, workQueue)
```